# wsgi:error ModuleNotFoundError in my webapp model

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

Hello IT ladies and IT gentlemen.

Please, help me with non-recognized folder "devices".

I have a program for reading data from robot. And data are stored in "devices" folder.

My file structure:

- GRP
- - devices
- - - _ _ init _ _.py
- - - dev1.py
- - - dev2.py
- - - dev3.py
- - - webapp.py
- - tools
- - - _ _ init _ _.py
- - - tool1.py
- - - tool2.py

Content of _ _ init _ _ .py in devices folder:

```
__all__ = ["dev1", "dev2", "dev3"]
from dev1 import Dev1Cls
from dev2 import Dev2Cls
from dev3 import Dev3Cls
```

Problematic part of code in webapp.py:

```
from devices import Dev1Cls
```

And... Dev1Cls is class in dev1.py

I have flask Webapp (blabla/grp_exp_structure/devices/webapp.py) whose task is to read data and display them. Webapp reads data from dev1, dev2 and dev3 and that webapp is launched from Apache server via mod_wsgi.

If I run app via built-in Werkzeug server, no problem.
But if I run app by start Apache, I get exception ModuleNotFoundError in errorlog:
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'devices'**

Code of app.wsgi:

```
#! C:/Users/pvachal/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe

import sys

sys.path.insert(0, "c:/users/pvachal/documents/projekty/grp_exp_structure/devices")

activate_this = "c:/users/pvachal/documents/projekty/grp_exp_structure/venv/scripts/activate_this.py"
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

from webapp import Webapp
application = Webapp().app
```

Code of dev1.py (dev2 and dev3 are similar)

```
class Dev1Cls:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = "dev_number_one"
```

What do I have to do to make it work? I want to leave same file system what I have. Yes, I can change the structure of my files but I'm wondering how to solve this problem without changing the structure.

I think that problem is with non-reading of _ _ init _ _ file. When I run webapp.py directly, everything is alright because _ _ init _ _ file will launch. What I need to do to make it run without problems via wsgi? Is it possible to make _ _ init _ _ run via wsgi too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messing with `sys.path` is a terrible, terrible idea – with what you've done, you probably have two ways of importing `dev1` etc: `from devices import dev1` and `import dev1`, and a splitting headache.

**If** your WSGI environment needs it (e.g. you can't `chdir` or otherwise set a project root via mod_wsgi), you *can* prepend the project root, e.g. `sys.path.insert(0, "c:/users/pvachal/documents/projekty/grp_exp_structure")` in the WSGI entrypoint file but do *not* under any circumstance add a package (i.e. something that contains an `__init__.py` file).

Now that you've fixed that, you'll need to change the absolute imports in `devices/__init__.py` to be relative, or to mention the package:

```
__all__ = ["dev1", "dev2", "dev3"]
from .dev1 import Dev1Cls  # or `from devices.dev1 ...`
from .dev2 import Dev2Cls
from .dev3 import Dev3Cls
```

Similarly, fix the import for webapp in the WSGI file:

```
from devices.webapp import Webapp
application = Webapp().app
```

and finally, if `devices.webapp` contains other imports that would have been absolute if `devices` was on the path, fix those up like above too.

In general, even outside of a WSGI context, you can now test that things are sane with a `something.py` in the `grp_exp_structure` directory:

```
import devices
from devices.webapp import Webapp
```

These imports should both work fine.

(Finally, as an aside, I would recommend to look at something other than Apache + mod_wsgi.)

Comment: **SOLVED**
Mr. AKX, thanks a lot!
Incorrectly set address in insert to sys.path in app.wsgi - that was my problem.

After rewrite addr on **c:/users/pvachal/documents/projekty/grp_exp_structure** my app runs and **folder "devices" was imported**.

Of course... I must set addr to higher level than folder "devices".

In short: Which server for Python frameworks is better than Apache? (I'm beginner in these things...)

Comment: For development, you could use [Werkzeug (linking directly to tutorial)](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/tutorial/#intermezzo-running-the-application); for deployment, I'd go with Gunicorn or uWSGI.